# phprunner drop-down list -default value

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I have a drop-down list of US states in my db. Each record has details of the user etc. now when i try to edit the user details, the drop-down list should retain the original value of the state but it says "Please select". The whole purpose to do this is to make sure the state is not changed automatically.

This is what I have

```
//create dropdown box 
$str = ""; 
$str.= "<select onchange=\"window.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;\"><optio‌​n value=\"\">Please select</option>"; 

//select values from database 
global $conn; 
$strSQL = "select states from states"; 
$rs = db_query($strSQL,$conn); 
while ($data = db_fetch_array($rs)) 
 $str.="<option value=\"states_list.php?a=search&value=1&SearchFor=".$data["selected"]."&SearchO‌​ption=Contains&SearchField=company\">".$data["selected"]."</option>"; 

$str.="</select>"; 
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the code put in a

```
selected="selected"
```

in the `<option>` tag of the state option that should be selected.

Comment: here is what I have:


//create dropdown box
$str = "";
$str.= "<select onchange=\"window.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;\"><option value=\"\">Please select</option>";

//select values from database
global $conn;
$strSQL = "select states from states";
$rs = db_query($strSQL,$conn);
while ($data = db_fetch_array($rs))
$str.="<option value=\"states_list.php?a=search&value=1&SearchFor=".$data["selected"]."&SearchOption=Contains&SearchField=company\">".$data["selected"]."</option>";

$str.="</select>";
echo $str;

where states is the table

Comment: You need to have some kind of `if ($data["state"] === $user["state"]) echo ' selected="selected"';` inside your `while`-loop and output this attribute inside the `<option>`-tag. To understand the process, try out the following example: `<select><option>first option</option><option selected="selected">second option</option></select>`.

Comment: @user1236077: In the code you posted above, where do you get the value that it should be? You will need to fetch the user details from the database in order to pre-populate the form. If you get the value from the database and store it in a variable, call it `$selectedData`, then in your `while` loop, when you create each option, you need to add something like ` ". ($data["selected"] == $selectedData ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "") ." inside your `option` tag.

Comment: @user1236077 I don't understand your code enough to write a full solution, but before the end of the `<option>` tag you need to have an `if` control that returns `selected="selected" if true, are you defining variables that allow this?

Comment: never mind. I had to fix things here and there. thank you for your help.